# request parameters need to be populated with out validation in struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, interceptor

I have a struts Action Class with method searchUser() now I want to call this method. So i have following configuration in struts.xml

```
<action name="searchUser" method="searchUser" class="test.User">
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="excludeMethods">searchUser</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result name="success">/jsp/userAdded.jsp</result>
<result name="input">/jsp/user.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

My test.User.java class

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{
  String loginId;
  //getter and setter method for loginId;

public String searchUser(){
   System.out.println(getLoginId());
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

Now when I tried to access this action using URL :/app/searchUser.action?loginId=1 then as per my understanding console should display "1" but it is having null. I want to access action from URL not from struts form.

If i remove validation interceptor then I am getting "1". I want to skip validation, so please help me how can I get value "1" with out validation, is there any other way. I want to get request parameters populated with out using validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it changing the configuration for the default package instead doing it in the action:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">searchUser</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    ....
<package />
```

There, you can configure few actions and you can use * symbol. For example:

```
<param name="excludeMethods">search*, remove*</param>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with the validation interceptor behaviour per-se. By configuring your action with

```
<action name="searchUser" method="searchUser" class="test.User">
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="excludeMethods">searchUser</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result name="success">/jsp/userAdded.jsp</result>
<result name="input">/jsp/user.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

you have told struts to use the Validation interceptor and ONLY the validation interceptor for this action. So all the other interceptors are ignored - including the Parameter interceptor which is responsible for passing HttpResponse parameters into your action.

When you remove the validation interceptor from your configuration, then Struts uses the default stack - the Parameter interceptor is called again and hey presto your HttpResponses are returned to your action.

What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer..I am actually trying to integrate Jquery datatable with struts2 action. So jquery will send request directly with URL using ajax call...

Answer (score 1):

The default intercepters meybe overwrited. Try this:

```
<action name="searchUser" method="searchUser" class="test.User"> 
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="validation.excludeMethods">searchUser</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result>...</result>
</action>
```